# Android write to secondary external storage (Permission denied)

Tags: android, file-permissions, filenotfoundexception, android-sdcard, permission-denied

When I am trying to write to a file in secondary external storage (SD Card), I am getting the following error:

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: /storage/70F7-83E4/file.txt (Permission denied)
```

I have added the following permissions to my manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

I am also requesting permission at runtime.
I have also downgraded from SDK 30 to SDK 28 and also tried adding the following to manifest file:

```
 android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true"
```

I don't understand what I am doing wrong, but I am still unable to write to secondary external storage (SD Card).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Removable micro SD cards are not writable since Android Kitkat.

Except for one app specific directory.

Comment: But many apps I see on the play store are able to write to anywhere on the external storage just fine.

Comment: Is it? You are not exact. To some external storage locations ok. But to a removable micro SD card? No.  Where did you see such?

Comment: On play store there is a Text Editor by Byte Mobile: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.byteexperts.texteditor&hl=en_IN. This application for example can write to removable micro SD card perfectly fine.

Comment: Every application can write to its own app specific directory on a removable micro sd card using classic file system code. And to the whole card using Storage Access Framework code. Your app can too. You dont need any permission at forehand.

Comment: I have looked into Storage Access Framework. I am now able to write to files on secondary external storage (SD Card) as well. However, I also need to be able select files of only a custom file extension (.fgz). Is there some way we can handle this with SAF?